# WPF 3D element rotation speed dynamic control

Tags: wpf, animation, 3d, storyboard

I have some 3D Geometry that resembles a wheel. I want to be able to rotate it but in a controllable way. I have a slider and I want to change the speed of the wheel's rotation according to the slider value without having to stop it. What is the best way to achieve that.

I know how to rotate it to a certain degree and I also know how to have some continuous Storyboard that rotates the wheel. But I don't know how to change that according to the slider's value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing a lot with it, I did it. This is how:

1. Created a **Storyboard** with a "Forever" **RepeatBehavior**
2. In my code, as I receive info from USB -not from a slider anymore- I change the Storyboard's **SpeedRatio** accordingly (You can also bind it to a slider progress or whatever else)